# Variables in an Array - Javascript

Tags: arrays, variables

i'm trying to put the variables cord1x and cord1y into the segments array but it doenst work.

here is my code:

```
var cord1x = 121; 
var cord1y = 446;  
segments = [{x: cord1x, y: cord1y}];
```

how do i become the variables into the segements string?

Comment: What does _"it doesn't work"_ mean?

Comment: `segments` is an array containing one object. Define "doesn't work".

Comment: I don't understand the last paragraph at all. "How do I become" seems to imply _you_ changing into something else, which is clearly not meant here.

Comment: Your segments is not a string. Its an array with has one element. 

    console.log(segments[0].x)

will return 121.

To create a segment with x and y variable then type segments = {x: cord1x, y: cord1y}

Comment: i want to draw a path with these coordinates but i want to keep the x/y coordinates variable. so i thougt i can change the numbers with variables like "cord1x" "cord1y" and so on. so my question is how i can do this. :)  

segments = [{x: 121, y: 446}, {x: 164, y: 384}, {x: 190, y: 271}, {x: 186, y:198}, {x: 180, y:60}];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, perhaps [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is what you want:

```
segments = [];

//foreach point in some set
  // compute cord1x, cord1y
  segments.push({x: cord1x, y: cord1y});
```

Then `segment` becomes an array of objects, each representing one 2d point, consistently with your example of `segments = [{x: 121, y: 446}, {x: 164, y: 384}, {x: 190, y: 271}, {x: 186, y:198}, {x: 180, y:60}]`

---

Based on the question alone:

With `segments = [{x: cord1x, y: cord1y}];`, `segments` becomes an array containing one anonymous object. `cord1x` becomes accessible as `segments[0].x` and `cord2x` becomes accessible as `segments[0].y`.

With `segments = {x: cord1x, y: cord1y}`, `segments` becomes an object with the properties `x` and `y`. `cord1` becomes accessible as `segments.x` and `cord2` becomes accessible as `segments.y`.

With `segments = [cord1x, cord1y]`, `segments` becomes an array of two integers. `cord1x` becomes accessible as `segments[0]` and `cord1y` becomes accessible as `segments[1]`.

With `segments = '{x: '+cord1x+', y: '+cord1y+'}'`, `segments` becomes a string in the form `{x:121, y:446}`. The downside is that `cord1x` and `cord1y` are not as easy to retreive. The upside is that `segments` can now be compared for equality, instead of identity, by using `===`.

Comment: hey jan. thank you very much! that helped me a lot. your second comment was what i looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

For that you would use the push method in javascript.

```
var coordinate1 = Coordinates.getCoordinate(100, 200);
var coordinate2 = Coordinates.getCoordinate(200, 300);
var coordinate3 = Coordinates.getCoordinate(300, 400);
var coordinates = [coordinate1, coordinate2];
coordinates.push(coordinate3)
```

You can find out more at w3 schools http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: I don't recommend referencing w3schools. Use MDN instead. There's plenty of terrible advice on that site. Also, why are you using fruits in your example (except because that example is copy-pasted from that site)?

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
var Coordinates = function() {};

Coordinates.onLoad = function() {
    var coordinate1 = Coordinates.getCoordinate(100, 200);
    var coordinate2 = Coordinates.getCoordinate(200, 300);
    // access them like coordinate1.x, coordinate1.y 
};

Coordinates.getCoordinate = function(x, y) {
    var coordinate = {
        x: x,
    y: y
    };
    return coordinate;
};
```

Comment: Do you realise `Coordinates.onLoad` never gets called except manually?